# Probability of a 36 recording sample size containing at least 3 male recordings out of 48 total recordings with 26 male and 22 female

Tags: probability

This seemed like a pretty straightforward hypergeometric distribution problem to me, but I got this problem wrong, and I'm not sure why.  Could anyone help straighten me out?

**Problem:**
The MIT-BIT arrhythmia database contains 48 heart signal recordings with 22 and 26 from female and male patients, respectively. For a classification task, an analyst randomly selects 36 records for predictive model training and keeps the other 12 records for testing the model performance.

*What is the probability that at least three male patient recordings are selected for training?*
**My answer: 1.00**
$N=48$
$K=26$
$n=36$
$n+K=52>N$, therefore, at least $n+K-N$ successes must occur in the sample.
$n+K-N=36+26-48=14$, so
$P(X\leq 14)=1$
$14>3$ so since we always have at least 14, then we always have at least 3.

Alternatively, you could solve this explicitly and the answer is still 1:
$P(X\geq 3)=1-P(X< 3)=1-\left ( P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2) \right )$
$P(x=2)=\frac{\binom{26}{2}\binom{22}{22}}{\binom{48}{36}}=0$
$P(x=1)=\frac{\binom{26}{1}\binom{22}{22}}{\binom{48}{36}}=0$
$P(x=0)=\frac{\binom{26}{0}\binom{22}{22}}{\binom{48}{36}}=0$
$1-(0+0+0)=1$

So where've I gone wrong here?

Comment: Hmm odd. Indeed with the pigeon hole principle, it's impossible to have less than $36-22 = 14$ male patient recordings. What an odd question. It's because even if one aims to choose only females, they run out of females pretty soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $1$. The fact, as already understood, is that any sample with size greater than $24$ will certainly contain at-least $3$ men.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, it looks like 1 to me. The only thing I'd point out is that P(X<=14) =  1. CMIIR, but you're guaranteed to have at least 14 males. What you wrote, P(X >= 14), probably concerned with picking more than 14 males. Don't know if you lost points for that.

Regardless, this is probably a classic instance where your professor was lazy and switched "training" with "performance." At least with 12 picked out, you can solve it with combinations.

Comment: John, good catch - looks like it was a typo as I was trying to write everything out in Latex.  I'll correct the question. I see you're new to the site - for future reference, this type of contribution would be better left as a comment than an answer, though IIRC new members can't leave comments until they earn so much reputation, so..... <shrug/>